# Add tabs and enters on docbook

Tags: docbook, docbook-5

How can I add tabs or enters in a docbook file?
I am writing a documentation of a server commands, and I need to use tabs and enters in the docbook file, I think the para tag will not work in my case.

below is an example of what im trying to achieve:

```
<login type="password">
    <username>
        usuario
    </username>
    <password>
        contraseña
    </password>
    <web>true</web>
</login>
```

how can i create something that is look like that or similar?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but perhaps the [cmdsynopsis](http://docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/cmdsynopsis.html) element is what you are looking for?

Comment: i'm using literallayout, the bad thing it's that the tab character doesn't work,so i use 4 white spaces to approach the tab print.
example:
`<literallayout>&lt;login type="ldap"&gt;
    &lt;username&gt;
        usuario
    &lt;/username&gt;
    &lt;password&gt;
        contraseña
    &lt;/password&gt;
    &lt;web&gt;true&lt;/web&gt;
&lt;/login&gt;
     </literallayout>`

Comment: What do you mean by "the tab character doesn't work"? Why do you need to use tabs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set newline and tab in paragraph using xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051289/how-to-set-newline-and-tab-in-paragraph-using-xslt)